# Raspberry Pi Zero as boot keyboard USB gadget

Tags: linux, usb, keyboard, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to turn Raspberry Pi Zero W as a "boot compatible" keyboard (USB gadget). I've followed [this tutorial](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/raspberry-pi-zero-usb-keyboard-hid/) to make it work in OS, i.e. when plugged into a Mac computer that has been powered on and logged into a user, I can send keystrokes via Raspberry Pi to the Mac by running scripts writing bytes to device file (/dev/hidg0).
The tutorial makes use of two modules: dwc2 and libcomposite.

However, I need the Pi to work as a keyboard in Mac's EFI (BIOS). Specifically I want to send Command+R keystroke as the Mac is booting up to enter the recovery mode.

Looking at [the official document](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hid1_11.pdf) from the USB org, boot keyboards require support for SET_PROTOCOL and GET_PROTOCOL requests from the host (Appendix B.1 and F.3). I did modify the report descriptor as shown in Appendix B.1.

According to line 496 to 606 in [this class](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/6f84467f66ba847e643489a3d18b1cf81bad87d0/drivers/usb/gadget/function/f_hid.c) in Raspberry Pi Linux source code, it seems like the module supports SET_PROTOCOL and GET_PROTOCOL requests.

However, Pi as keyboard gadget does not work in EFI; only in OS.

Does libcomposite not include f_hid.c class? If not, does anyone have any insight into how to implement a boot keyboard gadget? I feel like I am missing something.

Thank you very much in advance!

Fyi, [this is my report descriptor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/439Il.png).

Comment: I'm not a moderator, but if I were, I'd move your question to the Raspberry Pi Stackexchange: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ it's quite an interesting question.